# Display data (fetched from DB) into InputTextarea Blazor

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to display some data fetched from database into a Textarea of my Razor page.
I have tried out something like this. Is this the correct way of displaying the data for view only?

Razor page code snippet:

```
 @if(summaryProjection != null)
            {
               
                    <div> Seller Data</div>
                    <textarea>
                       @summaryProjection.tradeSummary.articleCurrency
                    </textarea>
            }
```

cs side code:

```
public Models.SummaryProjection summaryProjection = new Models.SummaryProjection();
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            string Id = TID;
            summaryProjection = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Models.SummaryProjection>($"api/T/summary?Id=" + Id);
           
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a block of text you want to display then `textarea` is as good a solution as any other (with some css formatting to make it pretty).  You will need to add `disabled` to prevent editing.  In your example you appear to want to display a currency value.  for that it's not the best - just use a suitably styled input, again with `disabled` set.

```
<textarea disabled>
    @summaryProjection.tradeSummary.articleCurrency
</textarea>
```